# Говорят ли так?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Меня интересует, говорят ли (пусть и неправильно) вместо "выслать письмо через кого-то" — "выслать письмо с кем-то"?

Речь не о передаче письма из рук посыльного, а об отправке по почте человеком, который делает это как посредник, от своего имени. Или даже так не говорится?

Comment: Ситуация описана совершенно неясно,  запись некорректная, поэтому желательно редактировать и то и другое.

Comment: "Говорят ли так?"  КАК? Контекста-то нет.

Answer (score 1):

"Выслать письмо с кем-то"- это точное указание, что этот "кто-то"его доставит сам.

Тогда уж не "выслал", а "передал на почту".

"Письмо было точно отправлено, я передал его на почту с Александром".

А к чему такие сложности? Почему нельзя сказать: "Александр доставил письмо на почту и отправил его"?

Answer (score 0):

Этот кто-то, «*который делает это как посредник, от своего имени*», — лицо доверенное. Посылают (отправляют) доверенного с письмом, а не письмо с ним. И никак — «*через него*».

Если речь идёт о переписке виртуальной, то надо говорить о высылаемом письме с эл. адреса человека или **пересылаемом им** какого-либо прежде полученного письма. В этом случае переправить письмо через третий почтовый ящик (по договорённости или дистанционно) будет условно означать «выслать письмо через кого-то», т. е. с его же электронной подписью. Другой вариант — *с кем-то* — не проходит.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/14965)

Comment: Morkovkin! У автора просили другие, как видите. Те, кто не понял суть вопроса. Вы, наверное, поняли. Ждём ответа.